# Replicating the speed of XLOOKUP in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Each week I prepare a non-rotating materials report that other people work with during the week. This report contains four tabs, each for a different category of materials. Materials can switch categories between weeks. Next to each material there’s a cell for other users to leave their comment. So that I don’t waste time manually updating user comments in the new report I’ve written myself an Excel formula that’s basically =XLOOKUP(1)& XLOOKUP(2)&XLOOKUP(3)&XLOOKUP(4). It executes instantly and without problems.

I’ve tried replicating the same effect in VBA and I’m not quite satisfied with the result. It works, but it takes several seconds rather than happening instantly. That means it’s in some way inefficient. Here's the code:

```
Sub LookUpMacro()

Workbooks.Open "#Censored#\Previous Non-Rotating Materials Report.xlsx"
ThisWorkbook.Activate

Dim commentColumnSize As Integer
Dim commentQuartet(1 To 4) As String
commentColumnSize = Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count - 1

For i = 1 To commentColumnSize
commentQuartet(1) = Application.XLookup(Range("A" & i + 1), Range("'[Previous Non-Rotating Materials Report.xlsx]Category1'!$A:$A"), Range("'[Previous Non-Rotating Materials Report.xlsx]Category1'!$J:$J"), "")
commentQuartet(2) = Application.XLookup(Range("A" & i + 1), Range("'[Previous Non-Rotating Materials Report.xlsx]Category2'!$A:$A"), Range("'[Previous Non-Rotating Materials Report.xlsx]Category2'!$J:$J"), "")
commentQuartet(3) = Application.XLookup(Range("A" & i + 1), Range("'[Previous Non-Rotating Materials Report.xlsx]Category3'!$A:$A"), Range("'[Previous Non-Rotating Materials Report.xlsx]Category3'!$J:$J"), "")
commentQuartet(4) = Application.XLookup(Range("A" & i + 1), Range("'[Previous Non-Rotating Materials Report.xlsx]Category4'!$A:$A"), Range("'[Previous Non-Rotating Materials Report.xlsx]Category4'!$J:$J"), "")
Range("J1").Offset(i, 0).Value = commentQuartet(1) & commentQuartet(2) & commentQuartet(3) & commentQuartet(4)
Next i

Workbooks("Previous Non-Rotating Materials Report.xlsx").Close

End Sub
```

I’m interested to know why it might be that my code executes slower than in-sheet calculations and how could I improve it?

Comment: Alternatively, you could have VBA write the formula for you, which may be quicker. It could also then copy the results into values, this would then mean the workbook is no longer referencing other workbooks, but this would only be useful if you know that the comments will not change.

Comment: Accessing Excel from VBA is slow.  If you need to make multiple references to a Worksheet in a calculation it is best to move the relevant section of the worksheet into a VBA array.

Answer (score 1):

There are two inefficiencies in your code.

- You rely on Excel functions. Although they could be efficiently implemented, at least on version that I worked with, they use some linear search, therefore using a `Scripting.Dictionary`, which uses hashtables (or maybe a binary tree, I can't recall it right now), is much faster.
- Changing the value of cells one by one is slow because each communication (google for "COM marshalling" if you are interested) between Excel and VBA has a fix cost, independent of the number of cells changed at once.

I would do something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub LookUpMacro()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks.Open("#Censored#\Previous Non-Rotating Materials Report.xlsx")
    
    ' Include: Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim dct As Scripting.Dictionary: Set dct = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    Dim s As Long: For s = 1 To 4
        Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Category" & s)
        Dim colJ() As Variant: colJ = ws.UsedRange.Column("J").Value
        Dim colA() As Variant: colA = ws.UsedRange.Column("A").Value
        Dim r As Long: For r = LBound(colA, 1) To UBound(colA, 1)
            Dim key As Variant: key = colA(r, 1)
            Dim valueToAdd As String: valueToAdd = colJ(r, 1)
            If Not dct.Exists(key) Then
                dct.Add key, valueToAdd
            Else
                dct(key) = dct(key) & valueToAdd ' or maybe: dct(key) & " " & valueToAdd
            End If
        Next
    Next
    
    colJ = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange("J").Value ' TODO: replace Sheet1 with actual name
    colA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange("A").Value ' TODO: replace Sheet1 with actual name
    For r = LBound(colA, 1) To UBound(colA, 1)
        key = colA(r, 1)
        Dim valueFull As String: valueFull = dct(key)
        colJ(r, 1) = valueFull
    Next
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange("J").Value = colJ
    
    wb.Close
End Sub
```

I did not test this code, but would like to underline that you must include Microsoft Scripting Runtime for this to work (you find it in Tools menu > References), and replace 'Sheet1' with the actual name of the sheet where you want to copy these comments.

Comment: I see some interesting ideas here, but first I'm going to experiment with UsedRange and LBound. I haven't seen them before and they look to be useful.

Comment: UsedRange should be the area that's used (has formulas, constants, is formatted, etc.), however, it is not updated when deleting something, only when adding something or saving the file. Therefore it always contents all used cells but may contain unused cells, as well. If you just opened the workbook, it should be accurate, and if it isn't it's no big deal.

Comment: LBound and UBound return the first and last valid index into an array. If you supply a second parameter, that means you want to get the bounds of that dimension of a multidimensional array.